# Prestashop: Theme

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5, prestashop-1.6

I have upgraded Prestashop from 15.6.X.X to 16.X.X.X. After the up-gradation, default-bootstrap is activated as a default theme.

When I try to active my theme, the front end page get blank page.

It showing an error, Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyException' with message 'Unable to load template file .

How can I activate the old theme in upgraded version?
Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you miss a .tpl on your theme, please try to re upload it. (Or maybe your theme isn't compatible with 1.6)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have checked with the theme provider. It doesn't support 1.6.

Answer (score 1):

There are often problems with Prestashop upgrades.
You need to completely fix all problems before using your template.
Try to option file config/defines.inc.php and change the site to dev mode

```
/* Debug only */
if (!defined('_PS_MODE_DEV_'))
define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);
```

All errors will show on your frontpage, try to fix all those errors and get your website totally works. Normal you will see problems with database, some tables was not successfully added new columns, then try to add those columns manually via your phpmyadmin

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

@2plus

Prestashop 1.5+ theme will not work in 1.6 there are lots of changes need. You can enable the debut mode and then you will find the error.

in 1.6 there is new tpl implement global.tpl may be that is missing.